# VSTO: About VSTO implementation undo operations

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, undo

I started using **VSTO** recently and found that if I modified Excel using code, I could not undo it. Looked for many places but did not find a suitable solution. You have to figure out how to undo it. The current method is to record the current selection in `SheetSelectionChange`, put it in the Stack, and backtrack when it needs to be undone. The downside to this solution is that `SheetSelectionChange` does not listen to old content when copying into the table from elsewhere. So how do I do undo in C#? Thank you for your reply.

**My Environment**
Platform : PC
Host : Excel
Operating System: Windows10

Comment: Am I right in thinking that you need it to be undoable via the regular undo action when using Excel?

Comment: Sorry, Excel cannot use regular undo when using the VSTO add-in.@Peter

Answer (score 0):

The Memento Pattern is a good approach to Undo/Redo. You store a state object on a stack, and load it back if you need to undo.

I wrote a C# library that implements it using delegates and generic stacks. This means that you can wire it up to your existing code and not need to write much custom code to use it. If you already have a type for saving state, and methods to save and load state, you can just use these.

Since you said that making use of the existing undo stack in Excel is not an option for you in this case, this library might be useful.

https://github.com/peterdongan/UndoService

https://www.nuget.org/packages/UndoService/